# StackOverflow Exception about window function on Spark 1.5.2

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and in order to move crosswise. I have used many lead functions.　When I run the programe and the stackoverflow Exception has happened.

Is it the cause of memory and how to do the memory tuning.

```
val win = Window.partitionBy(df("KEY1"), df("KEY2"), df("KEY3"),df("KEY4"))
                  .orderBy(df("A").asc)

val df1 = df.withColumn("rank", rowNumber.over(win))
  .withColumn("A1", col("A"))
  .withColumn("A2", lead("A", 1).over(win))
  .withColumn("A3", lead("A", 2).over(win))
  .withColumn("A4", lead("A", 3).over(win))
  .withColumn("A5", lead("A", 4).over(win))
  .withColumn("A6", lead("A", 5).over(win))
  .withColumn("A7", lead("A", 6).over(win))
  .withColumn("A8", lead("A", 7).over(win))
  ...........          // there're 250 lead window functions
  .filter("rank = '1'")

df1.show()
```

Exception Information:

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:232)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:232)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:232)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:249)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:232)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionDown$1(QueryPlan.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:93)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsDown(QueryPlan.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ResolveHiveWindowFunction$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(hiveUDFs.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ResolveHiveWindowFunction$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(hiveUDFs.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:249)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
```

Comment: It's not an answer to your question (if I understand correctly, you want to make your code run), but maybe refactoring your code can do the job. You your partitions are not too big, your code could be much faster if you use `collect_list` on your partition (using `groupBy.agg(collect_list('A).as("tmpList"))`), and then by generating a select statement doing `tmpList(i).as("A"+i.toString)`for each i.

Comment: Thank you very much for using the collect_list to improve the job.
But now I use spark 1.5.2 and the collect_list is exist after 1.6.0.
So, I need to look for other solutions...

Comment: Right. Anyway, I don't know if the order would be conserved. For using groupBy, probably you need to first compute a partition index with your window, the use a udaf to collect the information of each partition. Would you be interested in such solution? Otherwise, you can always checkpoint intermediate results in your implementation, but it's ugly...